# Set up different fonts for fragments of string in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a long string `txt` that I want to display as margin text in a plot using `mtext()`. The `txt` string is composed of another string `txt.sub`, as well as of a date string, which applies a specific format to a date command argument. However, I want to display the "date" part of that string only in bold.

The string is:

```
 date.in = as.Date( commandArgs( trailingOnly=TRUE )[1], format="%m/%d/%Y" )
 date = format(date.in, "%b %d, %Y")
 txt.sub = "Today's date is: "
 txt = paste(txt.sub, date, sep = "")
```

I tried the following

```
 ## Plot is called first here.
 mtext(expression(paste(txt.sub, bold(date), sep = "")), line = 0, adj = 0, cex = 0.8)
```

but the problem with this is that it doesn't paste the values of `txt.sub` and `date`, but rather displays literally the words "txt.sub" and "date".

Is there any way to get to the result I am looking for? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting one of the examples from the help page on [mathematical annotation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) (see example 'How to combine "math" and numeric variables'):

```
mtext(bquote(.(txt.sub) ~ bold(.(date))), line=0, adj=0, cex=0.8)
```